# HTML5/CSS3 Polyfill for wp-login.php

Tags: css, wp-login-form, html5

As a result of my customizing of wp-login.php, using HTML5 (e.g. placeholders etc.) and CSS3 (e.g. various selectors), I would like to polyfill for older browsers.

Does WordPress, by default, have polyfill scripts already baked into the login/admin area or do I need to begin enqueuing polyfill scripts of my own?

## Example:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_215432_oldbrowsersupport');
function wpse_215432_oldbrowsersupport() {
    wp_register_script( 'ie_html5shiv', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/html5shiv.min.js', __FILE__, false, '3.7.3' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ie_html5shiv');
    wp_script_add_data( 'ie_html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
```

Comment: No clue what are you asking. Mind editing your question to make it obvious? (why does a simple html form need a polyfill at all?) Anyway this sounds like a JS question which might be off-topic.

Comment: The log-in page works without polyfill.

Comment: @toscho ...therefore enqueuing my own polyfills isn't duplicitous.

Comment: It isn't necessary.

Comment: @toscho Not being a [Smart Alec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_aleck) but as per the first and second clauses of the first sentence of my question, _it is_ ("it" meaning "enqueuing my own polyfills" and "is" meaning "necessary").

Comment: @MarkKaplun See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a more general (non-WordPress specific) [question about polyfilling on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34964881/2971649) (I strongly recommend reading through the ensuing comments for context) which has lead me to the following answer:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_215432_oldbrowsersupport');
function wpse_215432_oldbrowsersupport() {

    wp_register_script( 'ie_html5shiv', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/html5shiv.min.js', __FILE__, false, '3.7.3' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ie_html5shiv');
    wp_script_add_data( 'ie_html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    //Note: Placeholder script (https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) covered by a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/html5-placeholder-polyfill/

    wp_register_script( 'ie_selectivizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/selectivizr.js', __FILE__, false, '1.0.3' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ie_selectivizr');
    wp_script_add_data( 'ie_selectivizr', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

}
```